# Format field containing integer in edit/view form

Tags: formatting, edit-form

I have a list with a field that contains an integer, let´s say 12345. In the edit/view form, the field is displayed as 12,345. How can I format the field so that it displays 12345? This is how the field looks in sharepoint designer.

```
<SharePoint:FieldLabel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="EmployeeNumber" />
<Comment FieldName="EmployeeNumber" FieldInternalName="EmployeeNumber" FieldType="Integer"    />
<SharePoint:FormField Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ControlMode="Display"  FieldName="EmployeeNumber" IncludeDescription="True"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, I am afraid there is no option to remove the comma. I have seen similar issues with dates, where a year would be rendered as 2,012 instead of 2012 for example.

Unless you have specific requirements, the easiest workaround is to use a text column instead of a number column.

Comment: If I change FormField to TextField, I get an error: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldNumber' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldText'.

Comment: What I meant was to change the column type from number to text, in the list settings (not in SharePoint Designer). I have edited my answer.